# Git push and pull are not working with Visual Studio Code 1.62.1

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I recently updated Visual Studio Code to 1.62.1 and now `git push` and `pull` are not working. It gets infinitely stuck on trying to push/pull. The same happens with the built-in terminal. I don't get any Bash line after this command and have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in order to terminate.

It was working flawlessly before the update though. So far I have checked the basic things like `git` being in `$PATH`, `git config -l` and `git version`.

I have also tested being able to push/pull from terminal. That works totally fine. In addition, this problem seems to happen with almost all versions of Git since I did test it with multiple SSH servers with Git 1.78, 2.32, and 2.17.

Hoc can I fix this?

I am on [macOS v10.12.0.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra) and Visual Studio Code 1.62.1 if that's of any help.

Comment: Are you sure it is 1.62.1 and not 1.62.2? [Downgrading from 1.62.2 to 1.62.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/fix-for-fatal-authentication-failed-for#comment123761649_69979523) worked for me.

Comment: This is a super [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ) (because it affects so many). A candidate for a canonical question is *[fatal: Authentication failed for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979522/)* (despite the unspecific title).